# Operation not allowed when running `sudo storcli /c0 /e252 /s1 set good`

Tags: raid, hard-drive, hardware-raid, storcli

I have a server with a LSI card running with RAID5. Recently the card sounded an alarm and it seems there is a problem with one of the drives.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State  DG      Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model            Sp Type
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:0    11 Onln    0 14.551 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST16000NM002G    U  -
252:1    13 UBUnsp  -      0 KB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST16000NM002G    U  -
252:2     9 Onln    0 14.551 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST16000NM002G    U  -
252:3    12 Onln    0 14.551 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST16000NM002G    U  -
252:4     8 Onln    1  1.745 TB SAS  SSD Y   N  512B MZILT1T9HAJQ/007 U  -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to fix the problem by following this guide http://sudoall.com/fix-raid-on-lsi-controllers-when-a-disk-is-shown-as-ubad/ but when running: `sudo storcli /c0 /e252 /s1 set good`

I get the error:

```
-------------------------------------------------
Drive       Status  ErrCd ErrMsg
-------------------------------------------------
/c0/e252/s1 Failure   255 Operation not allowed.
-------------------------------------------------
```

- I am unsure why this drive failed.
- I don't understand why this command does not work and how to fix it.

Comment: Oh my word - you're using R5 with 16TB drives - please stop that ASAP, R5 has been dangerous for over a decade now. We get people on here who have lost all their data on R5 arrays every few weeks - it's so dangerous that many pro-sysadmins consider it negligent for vendors to still offer it. I've typed this text so many times but people still use it. PLEASE move to R10/10, R6/60 or RAID-Z as soon as you can, otherwise you'll be along here wanting help to get your data back at some point or another.

edit - have you tried restarting the controller?

Comment: Oh I was not aware of that - none of the guides I looked at mentioned that this is so unadvisable. I have 4 drives in total so I thought that raid 5 might be okay in this case. I will try to switch to raid 6 as soon as possible then. Probably will need to buy another drive... In the mean time do you have any idea what could be happening in the problem I described?

Comment: Thanks for listening to me on this, we just get so many people coming here with lost data because of this issue. No direct idea what's going on with your array but if you can you should try rebooting the server or restarting your controller, there's a reasonable chance that'll sort out your problem.

Comment: @Chopper3, probably you mean RAID Z2, because RAID Z is (almost) equivalent to RAID5.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yeah probably, I'm no expert

Answer (score 0):

SF doesn't consider the above an "answer", so here's one.
Your best fix would be to set the HBA into JBOD/passthrough mode and use MD software RAID.